# mime type for text file through xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt, mime

I just want to know that what is the MIME type i need to give if i am generating text file from xml using xslt?

Answer (score 1):

text/xml likely won't be the narrowest type you can give, but it should work, since everything you are touching is xml.

Answer (score 1):

The MIME type has nothing to do with how a file was generated. It is used to assist the browser to display it correctly. If you want the browser to open it as text use "text/plain". If you want to open it as html use "text/html".